# REST server sampler for JMeter

Tags: rest, jmeter

I need to test a blackbox that outputs a POST request to a REST service.
Intend to use JMeter for this.

So my sampler should be a REST server and listen to post from the tested module.

What's the best way? Any ready-made solutions around? (seems like JMeter's REST sampler can only be a REST client)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure JMeter is the solution you're looking for here.  You can always start a JMeter proxy on the black box to catch everything that it sends out, but there's not much beyond that it can do.

If watching traffic is all you're doing, I think it would be simpler to ssh the destination server this black box is transmitting to and run

```
    sudo tcpdump -n dst port 8080 -A
```

Depending on what port the black box POSTs on, you can just change the above port.  You can stream these results to file and run whatever tests you need on these with a more appropriate testing tool/script.

Comment: What tool/script can you suggest?